# output from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a program which asks the user to enter names and student marks, this part is fine, the code is below. After this, the user must enter a name of a student from the original input and it must output their score.  This is where i'm struggling. any suggestions would be great! The code works fine for the first part. I know its a simple addition but i don't know where to start.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <script>
    
    {
    var i = 0;
    var outMessage = "";
    var studNames = new Array(5);
    var studMarks = new Array(5);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    studNames[i] = prompt('Enter next name - ', "");
    studMarks[i] = prompt('Enter next mark - ', 0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    outMessage = outMessage + studNames[i] + studMarks[i] + "\n";
    alert (outMessage);
    
    studNames[i] = prompt('Enter name - ', "");
    }
    
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why have i got -2 already?

Comment: I think because this sounds like homework.

Comment: it is homework, im trying to learn it.

Comment: Rion already posted a solution, so I'll refrain myself. :-) Good luck learning JavaScript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that each of the values in your array, you can use the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function to find which index a particular name exists at and use that to retrieve the score from the other array :

```
// Get the index that contains your name
var nameIndex = studNames.indexOf(nameToSearch);
// Check if it exists
if(nameIndex < 0){
    // The name wasn't found, consider prompting again
}
else{
    // It was found, so pull the corresponding value from your marks array
    var scoreForUser = studMarks[nameIndex];
}
```

Comment: it said unexpected end of input?

Comment: The code above should work just fine. This assumes that you will be populating your `nameToSearch` using another `prompt()` call. This code will also be placed after you have finished populating your arrays.

Comment: it doesnt run, just says unexpected end of input? maybe im doing something wrong?

Comment: Generally that means there is a syntax error somewhere. Perhaps a missing closing `}` or a missing `;`. What does your code look like? You can see an example of the changes above (and using a much smaller array) [here](http://jsbin.com/duxoro/edit?html,output).

Comment: whats happening is that its showing all entered input names and scores, but no further prompt for finding a specific name in the array